# Ubuntu 17 Nautilus Location bar display actual path for alias

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts, location

I have a folder shortcut on my desktop & when I open it & press CTRL L for the location bar, it displays a path like 
/home/username/Desktop/foldername

Just wondering if its possible to change the that behavior so the location bar displays the actual directory path of the folder.

ex. /var/www/html/foldername
Thanks

Comment: The location bar *should* already do this. How are `/var/www/html/foldername` and `~/Desktop/foldername` related? Are they a symlink?

Comment: Yes...if I ctrl shift drag a folder to my desktop it creates a link but the location bar path for that folder starts from /home/username/desktop...not from the root